# Primefaces Barcelona Theme - Charts still have old RIO theme

Tags: jsf, charts, primefaces, themes

recently got the Barcelona theme for Primefaces and lately started using some charts but it seems they don't reflect the Barcelona theme/skin at all. They still have the old RIO skin. Could somebody please enlighten me on how to solve this?

I have done some research and it seems that with other themes like Adamanthium you had to use the setExtender("skinChart"); method and so on to allow JQPlot to re-skin it for you using JS methods. Is there something similar for the Barcelona theme perhaps?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get this solved thank you. For anybody struggling with this in the future perhaps, the solution is as follows:

Ensure you copy the content of the charts.css to your project's resources folder as well as charts.js. After you've done that you can let jqPlot re-skin your charts using the following on your chart model, for example:

```
myPieChart = new PieChartModel();
myPieChart.setExtender("skinPie");
```

I hope this will help someone in the future.
Cheers.

Comment: The 'charts.css' and 'charts.js' from the theme you bought? Maybe you can explicitly point out where they are in the zip file...Thanks for finding out and reporting back... Might be something PF needs to add to their documentation.

Comment: I literally looked everywhere in the barcelona-layout.zip and couldn't find it anywhere. What I ended up doing is creating my own charts.css and charts.js files in my project and I copied the contents from the sources on the PF live demo here: 

[link](view-source:https://www.primefaces.org/barcelona/charts.xhtml). I hope this helps!